# Не работает SEO вывод на страницы

Tags: битрикс

Настраиваю в административном разделе SEO, но на страницы сайта ничего не выводится.[image: Админка][image: Настройки компонента на стр]

Answer (score 0):

Компонент bitrix:news не имеет соответствующих настроек. Однако, этот компонент, по сути, выполняет роль прокси, подключая нужный компонент в зависимости от URL. Подключает он [bitrix:news.list](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_list.php) или [bitrix:news.detail](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_detail.php).
Оба этих компонента имеют параметры: SET_META_KEYWORDS и SET_META_DESCRIPTION

Проверьте равняются ли эти параметры Y.  Смотреть в файлах:
<путь_к_шаблону_вашего_сайта>/components/bitrix/news/<имя_шаблона_новостей>/ news.php и detail.php.